# regex for numeric

Tags: java, regex

actually i have a file 
in those line i have to find a line that is "[12] 18383"
i am using this code

```
while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (read.trim().matches(" ^[0-9]*$ ")) {
                    String[] arrOfStr = read.split("[ ]");
                     int pid = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1].trim());
                    for (String a : arrOfStr)
                {
                    System.out.println(": terms >>>>>>>>>>>" + a);

                    }
                }
```

output : 18383
so from many lines i have to search one that is like above 
and then number outside the square bracket should print

Comment: Please show us one matching line and one non matching line.

Comment: Read up on regex, you then should note that ` ^[0-9]*$ ` doesn't work: `^` and `$` in most cases represent the start and the end of the input so any whitespace before and after those don't make sense. That being said the expression `^[0-9]*$` would mean "the entire input (line) needs to contain digits or be empty" (`String.matches()` acts similar to this btw). You need to update your expression to reflect the structure of the input, e.g. it needs to take the `[number]` part into account.

Comment: Use `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\d+]\\s+(\\d+)");` and then when reading lines, `Matcher m = pat.matcher(read.trim()); if (m.matches) { pid = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sir, thanks for your help, but i used this pattern it is not working,

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `]\s+([^\s]+)` for capturing after the square brackets.